# Image renderer with X Toolkit

Tags: xtk

I'm using scanner (not IRM) images to load 2D volumes, the contrast seems different more saturated comparing to ITK-Snap. Here is the screenshot of what I get :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHX5M.jpg

And with IT -snap :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tIv7.jpg

Any idea why this differences ?
Thank you

Comment: Is this a programming question or a how to use a specific scanner question?  If it's about the scanner it should probably be put on another q&a site.

Comment: It's a programming question about how to visual scanner image with The X Toolkit (XTK), I updated to title to be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, XTK doesn't read this dicom tag and crops all the negative values.

https://github.com/xtk/X/blob/master/io/parserDCM.js

Do you have one image you can share for testing?

I would add this tag to the parserDCM.js, and if this flag is ON, increment all the pixels values to make sure they are all positive.

Thanks